# Preventing too much recursion in Google Places requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps, recursion, google-places-api

I am currently making an application that takes in a source, a destination and a distance `d`, and returns a list of restaurants which are at most `d` distance from the route between the source and destination.

I first make a request to `DirectionsService.route()` to get the polyline coordinates. I then pass each of those coordinates to `radarSearch()` to get the `place_id` of each restaurant which are `d` distance from the corresponding coordinate.

After I get the `place_id`s, I pass them to `getDetails()` to get their details.

The above process works fine if the route is small enough and the distance is small enough. But on increasing either of the two, the recursion loop exceeds its maximum limit on Chrome and Firefox.

Here is my code -

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    distance = document.getElementById('distance').value/1000; // distance is in kms
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map_directions);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

    var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById('source').value,
        destination: document.getElementById('destination').value,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == 'OK'){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            for (i=0; i<response.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) { 
               polyline_coordinates.push([response.routes[0].overview_path[i].lat(), response.routes[0].overview_path[i].lng()]);
            }
            findRestaurants(0);           
        }
        else {
            alert('Directions request failed');
        }
    });
});
```

`findRestaurants()` gets the `place_id`s for the restaurants that are `d` distance from each of the coordinates. If I don't get an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, I query for the next set of coordinates, else, I wait for `1 second`. I also have a `Set()` - `place_ids` - to check whether I am getting a repeat restaurant.

```
function findRestaurants(searchIndex) {
    var curr_coords = new google.maps.LatLng(polyline_coordinates[searchIndex][0],polyline_coordinates[searchIndex][1]);
    var request = {location: curr_coords, 
                    radius: distance*1000,
                    type: 'restaurant'};
    service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {
        if (results != null) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    if (!place_ids.has(results[i].place_id)) {
                        place_ids.add(results[i].place_id);
                        restaurants.push(results[i]);  
                        addMarker(results[i]);                            
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            searchIndex++;
            if (searchIndex < polyline_coordinates.length) 
                findRestaurants(searchIndex);
            else {
                // All coordinates have finished being queried. Now get details of restaurants
                getRestaurantDetails(0);
            }
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(findRestaurants(searchIndex), 1000);
        }   
    });
}
```

`getRestaurantDetails()` then queries using `getDetails()` for each of the `place_id`s to get details. `checkforAuthenticity()` checks whether the restaurant details returned has at least an address, phone number and some photos. The logic is pretty much the same as for `findRestaurants()`; I wait for `1 second` if I get an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, else I query for the next `place_id`.

```
function getRestaurantDetails(index) {
    service.getDetails(restaurants[index], function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            if (checkForAuthenticity(result)) {
                    var curr_urls = [];
                    for (var j=0; j<result.photos.length; j++) {
                        curr_urls.push(result.photos[j].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 1600, 'maxHeight': 1600 }));
                    }
                    result['photo_urls'] = curr_urls;
                    authentic_restaurants.push(result);
                }
            else {
                markers[index].setMap(null);
            }
        }

        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            index++;
            if (index < restaurants.length)
                getRestaurantDetails(index);  
            else {
                console.log("details done");
                sessionStorage.setItem("authentic_unique", JSON.stringify(authentic_restaurants));
                return;
            }             
        }
        else {
            console.log('overshoot for details');
            setTimeout(getRestaurantDetails(index), 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

As I said, the above code works for small distances and small routes. The browser throws a recursion error if either of the two parameters gets too high. (I tried with a route of length 20km, and a distance of 100m).

Is there any way to mitigate this? I tried setting some limit till which each of the recursive function goes, like this -

```
total_restaurants = restaurants.length;
curr_start = 0;
curr_limit = 50;
while (curr_limit<=total_restaurants) {
    getRestaurantDetails(curr_start, curr_limit);
    curr_start += curr_limit+1;
    curr_limit += 50;    
}
```

But its basically doing the same thing, I guess. Since they're all asynchronous calls to the `Google Places API`, the recursive stack would just increase like previously. What I would preferably like, is some way to query for the first 50 coordindates/place_ids, and then query the next 50 ONLY after the first 50 are done. Edit: This would probably keep the recursion stack size at some reasonable size.